# How to consume ajax enabled wcf service in multilayer project

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-ria-services

I have two layer (1) Web and (2)Service
In web layer I have all the js and .aspx page and in the service layer i have all the Ajax enabled wcf service.

How to consume service in the web application by the JavaScript in Ajax call

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your service configurations, functionality, design. You can iterate with the web services in few different ways. [Calling Web Services from Client Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398995.aspx) is guideline from Microsoft. Of course you also can use libraries like jquery.